# Same Python code takes minutes in Django, while less than 1s in shell

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn

I have Python class where sklearn/scikit-learn is used to build DecisionTree. It runs under 1s if I execute in Django shell, like `python manage.sh shell`. Then I would load data from csv and call my class and `fit` function from DecisionTreeClassified.

However, if I try to incorporate the same code into Django view it takes 6 min. and 6 GB of RAM to finish.

Are the threads/multiprocess implicated?

**Update**:
I don't think, that the code is problem, but rather Django environment or WSGI is the cause. However, here is some code:

```
def myfit: 
   dt=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini', splitter='best', min_samples_split=2,min_samples_leaf=n*self.params.min_category,max_depth=self.p‌​arams.max_depth,max_features=None, random_state=None, min_density=None, compute_importances=None) 
   dt.fit(x_i,y) 
   start_time=time.time()
   dt.predict_proba(x_i)[:,1] #takes ages here
   print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"
   #Django - 301.682538033 seconds, Cli - 0.06 seconds
```

Comment: it is difficult to answer your question without more precise info on your code

Comment: Have you tried [profiling your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)?

Comment: It's entirely possible your template is somehow horribly broken. At the very least add some `print time.time()` statements to see if it's calling `myfit()` that slows down or all the Django crud around it.

Comment: I know where it stucks (please check excerpt of the code), but I struggle to understand why it happens only in Django.

Comment: I have added time profiling

Comment: @Dzidas Is there anything going on in a database during that time?

Comment: If you have `DEBUG = True`, try setting it to `False` and time it again

Comment: Are you sure your are passing the same data in the CLI and the Django API?

Comment: @ogrisel very good question - I wrote some mock, where same random data is passed to predict function and results are coming back instantly in Django. That suggest, that on Django side I messed up data input.